# mysql remote login from workbench does not work

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-workbench, remote-access

I want to connect a ubuntu (16.04) machine through mysql workbench and it gives the following error.

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '35.200.151.3' (10060 "Unknown error")

I checked the config for bind_address and it is *. 
I have created a new user and grant privileges with host % also.
I also checked if its a firewall issue and it is not. What else could cause this error ?

Comment: Have you restarted you mysqld service?

Comment: Yes I have done

Comment: Possible proxy issue. Can you connect via telnet/putty?

Comment: I am able to connect through putty.

Comment: Port is 3306 and opened? skip-networking in my.cnf is commented out?

Comment: Yes I checked these too :(

Comment: Well, the last thing - iptables. Flush it and restart ubuntu